# Former job laptop

Tags: management

I worked part time for business but left over a year ago. During my time there, my former employer offered to purchase a laptop for me that I could use for that job as well as for my main job. I even offered to pay for half of it but he said I didn;t need to. We have been in touch after leaving that job and no request has ever been made for the laptop, in over a year  and it was never told to me that it was only for my employ there. Now that there has been a personal friendship falling out, I am suddenly being asked for it back. Is this legal on their part?

Comment: We can't answer legal questions here, but if your former employer gave you this laptop specifically for work, and you no longer work for them, the most professional thing to do is to return it.

Comment: **Is this legal on their part?** - Probably. Why don't you just give it back to them?

Comment: Just because they forgot to collect right away, doesn't transfer the laptop to you. It was bought with the employer's money for work and probably expensed on the tax report.

Comment: You wrote "**my former employer offered to purchase a laptop for me that I could use for that job as well as for my main job**". Clearly, the purpose of the laptop was for the job ONLY, and the employer paid for it 100% with their money. Now that the employer asks for it back, you should return it to them. This laptop is NOT like a t-shirt or coffee mug that you can keep as a gift from the employer. BTW, you can call them and ask if they want to sell the laptop to you at a discount price. It is up to them either to want the laptop back or to sell it to you at a discount price.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* their box until you have a statement in writing that it isn't. If you make giving you that statement a financially attractive choice, they may do so. Or may not.

You could ask them if they'd consider selling it to you as used at a price you both consider fair. Half the original purchase price might or might not do it, depending on its age. Usually, the simplest metric for what it's worth is what identically configured hardware has recently been selling for on eBay. (Completed sales, not offers/asks.)

They might want you to bring it in so they could make sure all company data and licensed software owned by the company has been removed; back up data that is legitimately yours first. They might want you to turn in the old hard drive/SSD and buy a new one, which would be a nuisance and would add to your cost but could be managed.

If they don't see this as being worth their effort, all you can do is back up, return their machine, buy you own machine (new or used) and restore data you need from the backups. Exactly as you would if the machine was about to become unavailable due to hardware failure rather than social failure.

Answer (score -3):

They can legally ask you for anything they want in most of the World.

My policy when I finish with a client and things are no longer professionl is that I just ignore anything that doesn't clearly benefit me in some way. Anything else is just unsolicited spam if you think about it.

In your case since you don't want to return it, just let them keep following up with your spam folder until the unlikely event that you have to answer.

Comment: @Donald must have been in my junk mail.... good luck with that